# How do I hide Terminal windows using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

I am using an AppleScript where I need to open many Terminal Windows using:

```
repeat while counter > windowAmount
    tell application Terminal
       do script ""
    end tell
end repeat
```

Is there any way that I can hide the new Terminal windows that are opening up?
I am fine with it appearing in the dock but I don't want it to show any windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could *minimize* each *window* as it's created, although you'll see each *window* as it minimizes to the **Dock**, or you could *hide* each *window* as it's created. The latter of which would require additional *code* as some point to *unhide* the *window*.

To minimize the *window*:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ""
    set miniaturized of window 1 to true
end tell
```

---

To hide the *window*:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ""
    set visible of window 1 to false
end tell
```

To *uhide* the *window*:

```
tell application "Terminal" to set visible of every window to true
```

Comment: Can I do ```tell application Terminal to set visible of every window to false``` to hide all windows?

Comment: @Todd, RE: "Can I do `tell application Terminal to set visible of every window to false` to hide all windows?" -- If that line of _code_ is run by itself, then technically no because there are no _double-quotes_ around `Terminal`, and as such it's an _undefined variable_. If you were to place _double-quotes_ around `"Terminal"`, then yes.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just tried it and it worked without the double quotes.

Comment: @Todd, RE: "I just tried it and it worked without the double quotes." -- How are you running it?  In **Script Editor**, if you run `tell application Terminal to set visible of every window to false` by itself, it errors with: "**Script Error** The variable Terminal is not defined."  -- Application names are supposed to be _double-quoted_!

Comment: That seems weird! I am on macOS Catalina and it seems to work with ```tell application Terminal ...```.

Comment: @Todd, Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/mgKVgx9 of **Script Editor** in **macOS Catalina** having attempted to run "`tell application Terminal to set visible of every window to false`" and it **obviously errors outs as it should**, and I stand by my previous statements!